# Cannot to connect to the default network from inside docker containers

Tags: google-compute-engine, aerospike

I am trying to deploy an app on google compute, but I've hit a networking problem, the app consists of a front end (running inside docker containers deployed using a replication-controller) and a backend of aerospike nodes.

The aerospike nodes are not part or the container cluster, but they are in the same project, and both the container cluster and the aerospike nodes are running in the default network.

The aerospike nodes running with the default configurations

from inside the docker containers I am trying to do this

```
var client = aerospike.connect(internal-ip-of-aerospike-node, 3000)
```

but the connection fails, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit sketchy on how docker containers are run on GCE (or how you are doing it exactly) but IIRC an overlay network is built so that containers could be addressed in their own address space. This is usually done by creating a virtual network interface pair between the host and the container. To get out of the overlay network, a masquerade rule like this (from https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-container-ports-to-the-host) is added on the host system:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16       !172.17.0.0/16
```

The overlay network is supposed to chosen such as to not conflict with the host network but If this overlay network overlaps with the GCE internal network, connections from containers to the overlay network would not work.

I can't answer the question why it's not working, but I can suggest things to try:

- Give an external address to an aerospike node and try connecting to that. If it works, it suggests the problem is in the container networking.
- Spin up an unrelated test VM and try to connect to an aerospike node from
- Are there any firewalls in the GCE default network that could get in the way? Try to add an explicit rule to allow the traffic.

The usual way to debug these issues is to run something that creates a stream of (failing) requests and then try to see the packets flow on each step:

```
while :; do nc -w1 -n -v -z &lt;aerospike-ip&gt; 3000; sleep 1; done"
```

Then, tcpdump to see whether the connection attempts are there and what the packets look like:

- ip link show and/or ip addr show (to find the interface)
- tcpdump -n -v -c 10 -i <interface> tcp port 3000

And do this in:

- in container (should be eth0)
- on docker host, on the container virtual interface (veth<something>)
- on docker host, on the host network interface (eth0)
- on aerospike host (eth0)

This will help pinpoint where the problem occurs and the packet dumps might also reveal why the problem occurs.

Comment: I think the problem is with kubernetes, a ping from another VM, or from inside a docker container that I've created myself works